WebView inside Column not scrolling
we have a page where I want to have a Image on the top and a WebView below it. This worked somewhat if I wrap the WebView with a Flexible. But the problem with this solution was that only the WebView scrolled but the Image at the top was "sticky". So I tried to wrap the Column with a SingleChildScrollView but that didn't work.
Then I tried to wrap everything in a CustomScrollView, this also somewhat worked but I can't scroll to the end of the WebView.
Does somebody know how can I accomplish that? That I can scroll the complete page and not only the WebView?
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: CustomScrollView(            
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio:
                  widget.news.imageRatio == NewsImageRatio.sixteenByNine
                      ? 16 / 9
                      : 1 / 1,
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                image: widget.news.imageUrl!,
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            hasScrollBody: true,
            child: WebViewWidget(
              controller: _controller,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

This is the version where the WebView scrolls correctly but the Image at the top doesn't scroll.
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(widget.news.imageUrl)) ...[
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio:
                  widget.news.imageRatio == NewsImageRatio.sixteenByNine
                      ? 16 / 9
                      : 1 / 1,
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                image: widget.news.imageUrl!,
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
          ],
          Flexible(
            child: WebViewWidget(
              controller: _controller,
              gestureRecognizers: {
                Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
                )
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

